# Get the last day of the month given the month

Tags: ruby

How would I get the last day of a current month given the month number.

For example if the month is 8 (August 2014), how would I get the last day of the month? (The last day of August is the 31th). The function(8) would return 31.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The last day of August is 31.

Comment: If I did not answer your question correctly, please provide more info. I swear I'm not trolling for answer-marking…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Date::civil`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-civil):

```
require 'date'
Date.civil(2014, 8, -1).day
# => 31
```

According to the documentation:

> The month and
>   the day of month should be a **negative** or a positive number (**as a
>   relative month/day from the end of year/month when negative**).
>   They should not be zero.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why -1 get's the last day? ^^

Comment: @AustinTruong, According to the documentation I linked in the answer: The month and the day of month should be **a negative** or a positive number (**as a relative month/day from the end of year/month when negative**)

Comment: Austin, that's consistent with Ruby's way of extracting the last element or elements of an array (`[1,2,3][-1] #=> 3`) or the end of a string (`"abcd"[-2..-1] => "cd"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
def function(month)
  raise "invalid month" unless month.is_a?(Integer) and month.between?(1, 12)
  month == 12 ? 31 : Date.new(Date.today.year,month+1,1).prev_day.day
end
function(8)
# => 31
```

source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-prev_day